# Determine liminf$A_{n}$ and limsup$A_{n}$ for the $A_{n}$ of the following sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, limsup-and-liminf, measurable-sets

$$A_{n} = \begin{cases} (\frac{1}{n}-2 , 1) \ \ \ \ \ \text{if} \ n \ \text{is odd} \\ (0,3 + \frac{1}{n}) \ \ \text{if} \ n \ \text{is even} \end{cases}$$

This question is on a past measure theory final and I think I have the right answer but would just like a second opinion.

I have:

- limsup($\frac{1}{n}-2,1)$= ($-1,1$)
- liminf($\frac{1}{n}-2,1)$=($-2,1$)
- limsup($0,3 + \frac{1}{n})$=($0,3.5$)
- liminf($0,3 + \frac{1}{n})$=($0,3$)

I was also wondering if the way I formatted my solutions would be acceptable on an exam? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have two too many answers.  The sequence $A_n$ is one object, it doesn't break into separate answers for the even and odd cases. Also, in limsup and liminf, you are taking $n$ to infinity. That changes your answers, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you are on the wrong track. The question seems to be about the whole sequence $A_n$, and you have separately evaluated two subsequences of it (the odd and the even members). Whatever the result, it must have a *single* $\lim\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ and a *single* $\lim\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$.

To solve the problem: recall that $\lim\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ is the set of all elements contained in infinitely many $A_n$'s. This will turn out to be $(-2,3]$. Similarly, $\lim\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ is the set of those elements contained in all but finitely many of $A_n$'s, and it is easy to see that this set is $(0,1)$.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: @Jack I did make a mistake, now corrected. $\lim\sup$ is $(-2,3]$, not $(-2,3)$. (Why?)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\limsup_{n\to\infty} 3+1/n = 3$, $\liminf_{n\to\infty} 1/n- 2 = -2$, $\liminf_{n\to\infty} 0 =0$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} 1=1$. So in summary

- $\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n = [0,3]$
- $\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n = [-2,1]$

Comment: What definition of $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ are you using?

Comment: $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf_{k\geq n}a_k\right)$; similarly for limsup

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit